# How can I scroll down to the end of a dynamically loading webpage?

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

We are talking about a webpage which as much as your scrolling down new elements coming up, up to a point.

I have try:

1.`WebUI.scrollToElement(findTestObject('footer'), 30)`

2.`WebUI.executeJavaScript('window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight)', [])`

3.`WebUI.executeJavaScript('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)', [])`

4.`WebUI.executeJavaScript(‘window.scrollTo(0, **923** )’, [])`

…But none of this goes to the end of page. Any other idea?

Comment: Provide example website, and we can explore/discuss it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this script which does the "job":

```
try { 
  long lastHeight=((Number) WebUI.executeJavaScript("return document.body.scrollHeight", null)).longValue(); 

  while (true) { 
    WebUI.executeJavaScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);", null);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    long newHeight = ((Number)WebUI.executeJavaScript("return document.body.scrollHeight", null)).longValue();
    if (newHeight == lastHeight) { 
      break;
    } 
    lastHeight = newHeight;
  } 
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```